# Finding permutations in a parallel way

Tags: c#, algorithm, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, permutation

#### How can you write a program that finds all permutations of a sequence in a parallel way??

To be more exact, I'm writing a program to find all possible schedules for the courses a student wants to take.

Say a student wants to take **CC101**, and **CC102**.

There are 3 teachers that are teaching **CC101** (CC101.A, CC101.B, ...) and 2 that teach **CC102**.

The combinations would be

```
[CC101.A, CC102.A]
[CC101.A, CC102.B]
[CC101.B, CC102.A]
[...]
[CC101.C, CC102.B]
```

(of course, dismissing those where the classes collide/happen at the same time).

The way I'm currently handling this is with a recursive function that essentially looks like this:

```
private List<Schedule> Schedules {get; set;}
public FindSchedules(Course[] courses)
{
   FindSchedules(new sched(), courses, 0);
   return this.Schedules;
}

private void FindSchedules(Schedule sched, Course[] courses, int courseIndex)
{
   if(i>= courses.length)
   {
      //class property
      this.Schedules.Add(sched.Clone());
   }
   foreach(var class in Courses[courseIndex].Classes)
   { 
     if(sched.ConflictsWith(class) continue;

     sched.Add(class);
     FindSchedules(sched, courses, courseIndex +1)
     sched.remove(class);
   }   
}
```

This actually works pretty well, but for larger number of Courses with large number of classes, it can start to build up. (# of Possible combinations are Courses[0].Classes.Count * Courses[1].Classes.Count * ...* Courses[N].Classes.Count)

What I was wondering is if there is a way to make it work in parallel. I was thinking that I could maybe do `Task.Run(()=>FindSchedules(sched.Clone(), courses, courseIndex +1));`, but obviously I wouldn't want to make all of the calls like that, just the first few of them, and then their child calls be regular recursive calls.

Is there any existing algorithm strategy for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use ienumerbale and yield, instead of passing the list object again and again to the recursive method, and than use Parallel.ForEach to enumerate the ienumerable.

Comment: Just a side comment - but the problem you're describing is NP Hard. So it'll always build up exponentially. Paralilising it won't make it work much better. I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177836/algorithm-for-creating-a-school-timetable which goes into a bit more detail.

Comment: This is not really an algorithm design community.  Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Haedrian yeah, it builds up really fast, but I figured, hey if it is going to take N cycles to do it, and you have X cores.. you could probably get it done in ~1/X the time. Of course, 1/X of infinity would still suck, but for practical purposes, if doing takes 2 seconds vs 0.5 seconds, that's quite a gain.

Comment: @RandRandom could you elaborate on your solution? Oh how would this be translated to a Ienumberable/yield?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the references to a few papers proposing parallel algorithms for permutations.

[Parallel Generation of Permutations by Inversion Vectors](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6169840)

[An optimal parallel algorithm for generating permutations in minimal change order](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167819106800189)

[Parallel generation of permutations and combinations](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01933707)

[Parallel Generation of Permutations](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/26/2/97.full.pdf)